# How to access a ref nested inside a named slot

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I am using the @composition-api plugin with vue2.

In my code I have something that looks like this:

```
<template>
  <AComponent>
     <template v-slot:content>
        <div ref="ele">
            ...
```

and inside my setup function I have:

```
const ele = ref(null)

... 
onMounted(() => {
      
  console.log(rlr)

});

...
return {
  ele
}
```

This works great as long as the div is outside the nested template tag:

```
<template>
  <AComponent>
    <div ref="ele" />
    <template v-slot:content>
       ...
```

Not sure how to access it if it's nested.

I've tried accessing it via giving some parent a `ref` and then doing something like:

```
.$scopedSlots.content()[0]
```

I see a Vue element but not really the DOM element.

Comment: have you tried adding a watcher to it?  or using a $nextTick before accessing it?